# scipy.io.wavfile.read returns array filled with zeroes

Tags: python, scipy, wav

I would like to get data from wav file by using scipy.io.wavfile.read method:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav

frame,data = wav.read('Delta.wav','r')
print(data)
```

Unfortunately this code returns a 2D array filled with zeroes:

```
[[0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]]
```

Comment: Does anything change if you leave out the 'r' parameter and just call `wav.read('Delta.wav')` ? Also are you sure that the arrays are completely empty/ the audio doesn't just start later and end sooner than what is being displayed by `print(data)`?

Comment: Indeed, `'r'` is not even a valid parameter: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html. I have recently switched to pysoundfile, I find it easier to use.

Comment: Okey, there was something in the middle of nd.array. Just my blindness. But now my question is - shouldn't this array be in a form [no. of sample, value of sample]? If so, why 1st column hasn't got increment? I've written 440Hz signal into wav and it is working. But the array used to generate signal was like [no. of sample, value of sample].